# Tools for Migration from Verity to Solr

Tags: solr, migration, verity

Does someone know tools that can do a migration from Verity to Solr.

Our Actual code is using Verity K2 6.5 we are not using ColdFusion but Java/J2EE.

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://veritytosolr.riaforge.org/) is one. Its also on [Github](https://github.com/ksaini/Verity-to-Solr)

[Verity to Solr migration](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSCCDC2C74-DE46-4ea1-B42C-DDF4F623B704.html) also gives some Coldfusion snippets to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Correct me if I am wrong but it seems that it works only for Cold Fusion Collections. We are in a J2EE environment. (I edited my question to precise it)

Comment: CF runs on a Java runtime, so technically this could serve your needs. But I see what you mean. I got to hear about this from a project that was moving away from Coldfusion (not just Verity), but this is all I know of at this point :(

Comment: Is there a way you can tap into the source of the data? And have Solr indexes built fresh instead of migrating? If so, I would recommend that highly. You would need it eventually, to refresh indices.